# Permission denied when installing mlxtend (Python 3)

Tags: python, machine-learning, permissions, pythonpath, mlxtend

I am trying to install the python library mlxtend for machine learning purposes. I have tried several solutions, including:

```
pip install mlxtend
easy_install mlxtend
```

I also have read all the threads r regarding similar errors with no success. When I execute all this, the setup.py fails.

When I finally try to execute the setup.py that I downloaded directly from the library zip (I opened the cmd in the library unzipped window), I got this error message:

[image: Error message I got]

I use Python 3 in windows. Can anyone help me? I am thoroughly stuck on this issue.

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: did you try running it as Administrator?

Comment: Do you have the administration user?

Comment: Yes I do. This is my personal computer and I only have one user in it. Any guess?

Comment: When opening command prompt, `right click` it and `Run as administrator`.

Comment: It does not work! :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by following the instruction in this post: [Import oct2py says access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770473/import-oct2py-says-access-is-denied)