# Import oct2py says access is denied

Tags: python, octave, oct2py

I have installed Python anaconda environment, and installed oct2py using

```
(D:\Anaconda2) C:\Users\BNP>conda install -c conda-forge oct2py
```

When I try to import oct2py from anaconda prompt, it doesn't show any error

Anaconda prompt:

[image: anaconda prompt]

But when I try import oct2py from spder it says access is denied.

Comment: Why do you post a picture of what is ok instead of one with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to run the command as administrator?
[image]

Comment: are you running the comand with admin privileges?
What OS are you using?

Comment: my os is windows 8.1 64 bit

Comment: did you start your console with start as administrator option?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: something similar to that image

Comment: from anaconda prompt or normal command prompt i can import oct2py

Comment: If you want to install it on anaconda environment you should do it on anaconda prompt

Comment: problem is with spyder console..when try there import oct2py it says access is denied

Comment: open spyder console as admin

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: the same way as you open cmd as admin