# Issues importing mlxtend python

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, mlxtend

I'm new to python, so apologies if this is a silly question.

I'm trying to use mlxtend, and have installed it using pip. Pip confirms that it is installed (when I type "pip install mlxtend" it notes that the requirement is already satisfied). However, when I try and import mlxtend in python using "import mlxtend as ml", I get the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlxtend'". I used the same process for installing and importing pandas and numpy, and they both worked. Any advice?

I should note that I have resorted to dropping in the specific code I need from mlxtend (apriori and association rules), which is working, but hardly a good long term strategy!

I'm using python version 3.6.5.

Thanks!

Comment: Which python distribution are you using ? I think you install those package in a different one. Are you using an IDE or the terminal?

Comment: Do you have multiple version of Python installed?

Comment: Just the terminal

Comment: It's quite possible I have multiple versions. However, when I "where python" I get a directory which matches the install of mlxtend... specifically python is in c:\python\python36, and mlxtend is in  c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages

Answer (score 7):

I was able to install the package by doing below two things:

1. Run Windows Command as an Administrator (Refer to [Import oct2py says access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770473/import-oct2py-says-access-is-denied) )
2. Try this command in the Wondows Command:

   `conda install mlxtend --channel conda-forge`

Comment: Thanks this worked for me when running `from mlxtend.classifier import EnsembleVoteClassifier`

Comment: Worked perfectly on Anaconda. Accept the answer as correct one.

Comment: It worked for me, you have to run this command on Anaconda prompt (Run as administrator)

Answer (score 7):

I was faced with the same error when running on Google Colab.
here's what fixed for me:

```
%pip install mlxtend --upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue while using Anaconda, I tried to install it with Anaconda, however, Notebook didn't see it installed. You can also try to install it in CMD by just typing

`pip install mlxtend --user` or `pip3 install mlxtend --user`

After installing it with CMD, Notebook didn't give error for my case. Just reply if this helps. Good luck all.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue when I use this library with `python 3.7` but it is working for `python 2.7` and I don't know why!.

My workaround is to download the [source code](https://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend) and import each file you need that way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

conda install -c conda-forge mlxtend

Don't mix pip and Conda environments. Last time I did this I broke my Python and needed to reinstall everything again.

If you must deal with different environments using pip and conda because of many projects, use pyenv.