# How to avoid "WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied')" error while installing a library in anaconda

Tags: plotly, conda, installation-package

I am trying to install plotly library in conda (using the command - "*conda  install -c plotly plotly*") but cannot install through conda where the error displayed was: ("**WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied')**")

How can I overcome this error

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post error messages as text, not as images. Images cannot be indexed by search engines and won't help other users with the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import oct2py says access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770473/import-oct2py-says-access-is-denied)